# BadMethodCallException Method [header] does not exist on view. in View.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display messages in the error section from sender and receiver, both returning view `mes_res` from `MessageController`, but it is displaying an error message.

@controller method:

```
public function respone_msg($myid){
        $dd = DB::table('messeges')->where(['is_read'=>0,'sender_id' =>$myid  , 'receiver_id' => Session::get('id')])->get();
        $myCount = count($dd);
        var_dump($myCount);

        $sendmsesgesreal = DB::table('messeges')->where(['sender_id' => Session::get('id') , 'receiver_id' => $myid])->orWhere(['receiver_id' => Session::get('id') ])->get();

//return view('users.mes_res')->with(['msg_data' => $sendmsesgesreal, 'user_id' => $myid, 'conv_id' => $sendmsesgesreal[0]->conversation_id]);

        return view('users.mes_res')->with(['msg_data' => $sendmsesgesreal, 'user_id' => $myid, 'conv_id' => $sendmsesgesreal[0]->conversation_id])->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    
    }
```

view `mes_reg`:

```php
    <div class="messages-headline">
        
        <a href="#" class="message-action"><i class="icon-feather-trash-2"></i> Delete Conversation</a>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Message Content Inner -->
    <div class="message-content-inner">
            
    <?php

    
 foreach ($msg_data as $msg) {
     //

    if($msg->sender_id==Session::get('id') && $msg->receiver_id==$user_id) //conv_id
    { 
 
        $getuserdat1 = DB::table('profile_users')->where('user_id',$msg->sender_id)->get();

       // print_r($msg);
        
        if (count($getuserdat1)>0) 
        {
            $fullname=$getuserdat1[0]->fname.' '.$getuserdat1[0]->lname;
            if ($getuserdat1[0]->profile_images) 
            {
               $img11 = url('')."/public/uploads/".$getuserdat1[0]->profile_images;
            }
            else
            {
               $img11 = url('')."/public/users/images/user-avatar-placeholder.png";
            }
        }
        else
        {   
           $img11 = url('')."/public/users/images/user-avatar-placeholder.png";
        }

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" id="receiver_id" value="'.$msg->sender_id.'">';


        //print_r($img11);


        ?>
        
        <div class="message-time-sign">
            <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($msg->CreatedBydate)->diffForhumans() }}</span>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="message-bubble me">
            <div class="message-bubble-inner">
                <div class="message-avatar"><img src="{{$img11}}" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="message-text"><p>{{$msg->messeges}}</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>


    <?php }

    elseif($msg->sender_id==$user_id)
    //else
    { 
       //print_r($msg);
        // $receiverdata = DB::table('messeges')
        // ->where('sender_id',$msg->sender_id)->get();

        // print_r($receiverdata);

        //print_r($msg);

         

        $getuserdat11 = DB::table('profile_users')->where('user_id',$msg->sender_id)->get();
        
        if(count($getuserdat11)>0) 
        {
            if ($getuserdat11[0]->profile_images) 
            {
               $img111 = url('')."/public/uploads/".$getuserdat11[0]->profile_images;
            }
            else
            {
               $img111 = url('')."/public/users/images/user-avatar-placeholder.png";
            }
        }
        else
        {   
           $img111 = url('')."/public/users/images/user-avatar-placeholder.png";
        }

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" id="receiver_id" value="'.$msg->sender_id.'">';

        //print_r($img111);

        ?>
        
        <div class="message-time-sign">
            <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($msg->CreatedBydate)->diffForhumans() }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="message-bubble">
            <div class="message-bubble-inner">
                <div class="message-avatar"><img src="{{$img111}}" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="message-text"><p>{{$msg->messeges}}</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    <?php }
?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think the error could be any clearer. The `header()` method doesn't exist. Don't use it.

Comment: return view('users.mes_res')->with(['msg_data' => $sendmsesgesreal, 'user_id' => $myid, 'conv_id' => $sendmsesgesreal[0]->conversation_id])->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); this is line in which header is called

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#view-responses. You need to use `response()->view(...)->header(...);`.